# why not set background according to position[android]

Tags: android

in the following code when clicked button not set background image according to position of Imgid and only set first of image (p1.png) as background!

whynot set background image according to position of Imgid?

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    private Gallery gallery;
    private ImageView imgView;
    private int[] Imgid = {
            R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2, R.drawable.p3, R.drawable.p4
    };
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    
        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);

         gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
         gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

         gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 

            }
        });
         Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                setback(position);

            }
        });
    }

    public void setback (int position){
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(Main.this); 
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(Imgid[position]);
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                        try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }

    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return Imgid.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because your `position` value is not initialized. You need to initialized position value into `setOnItemClickListener(......)`.

Comment: try as per my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one `mPosition` Global Variable and  initialized `mPosition` variable like

```
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
         mPosition=position;
    }
});
```

and then used `mPosition` like

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setback(mPosition);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

have you given the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

in Manifest